# In detectron2 there are class IDs instead of class names

Tags: python, image-segmentation, detectron

[I finished training model for instance segmentation in detectron2 when I test images in training files there is no problem class names(apple,banana,orange) are written on the image but I downloaded some fruit images from the internet and class names are not written on the photos. There are class ID's.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI9JA.png)

```
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "model_final.pth")
cfg.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST = 0.5 
cfg.DATASETS.TEST = ("fruit_test", )
predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)

image_path = "/content/detectron2_custom_dataset/testimages/test2.jpg"

def on_image(image_path,predictor):
    im = cv2.imread(image_path)
    outputs = predictor(im)
    v = Visualizer(im[:,:,::-1], metadata = {}, scale=0.5, instance_mode = ColorMode.SEGMENTATION)
    v = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
    plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
    plt.imshow(v.get_image())
    plt.show()

on_image(image_path, predictor)
```

**In conclusion, I want test my model with I uploaded now and I don't want to have class id on the images. I want class names like orange,banana,apple on it**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for an easy solution, I came with this, which is the easiest IMO.

## Create a new Metadata class

```
Class Metadata:
    def get(self, _):
        return ['apple','banana','orange','etc'] #your class labels
```

then, provide Metadata in the Visualizer line

```
v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1], Metadata, scale=0.5, instance_mode = ColorMode.SEGMENTATION)
```

Otherwise, you're required to register a model with (a dummy) data or even 1 image with annotations, then load its metadata. Which I find a bit irrelevant at this stage, if you need it for the inference code only.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the labels by populating the `metadata` kwarg, which contains the mapping.

```
v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1], MetadataCatalog.get(cfg.DATASETS.TEST[0]), scale=0.5, instance_mode = ColorMode.SEGMENTATION)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the 'metadata = {}' in the Visualizer line to

```
{"thing_classes":['orange','banana','apple']}
```

the entire line would be

```
v = Visualizer(im[:,:,::-1], {"thing_classes":['orange','banana','apple']}, scale=0.5, instance_mode = ColorMode.SEGMENTATION)
```

based on the below code in draw_instance_predictions function (detectron2/utils/visualizer.py)

```
labels = _create_text_labels(classes, scores, self.metadata.get("thing_classes", None))
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple line works for me.

```
MetadataCatalog.get("YOUR_DATASET").thing_classes = [LIST OF YOUR CLASS LABELS]
```